# What constitutes a write action in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently developing a Flutter web application using Firestore for data persistence. The app is not live in production, so I'm the only one accessing this backend. There is only one collection that holds a single document, with many nested fields (6 levels deep). My understanding from looking at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing, is that reads are counted per doc, so every time I reload my app it should count as one read, yet in the last 4 hours since I started working today I already hit 1.7K reads (as reported in the usage tab). I know I haven't reloaded the app that many times, and there's also no hidden loop that calls the collection multiple times.
This is the Flutter code that calls Firestore:

```
final sourceRef=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("source");
var data=await sourceRef.doc("stats").get();
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: Can you share your code? Also do note that you are charged for reads for reading data from Firebase console as well.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I added the two lines that fetch the data in my app. Even if it refreshes the console it still wouldn't add up to that number.

Comment: Most likely another part of your code does that. Check the console for more details or search other read operations in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Firebase pricing, writes are defined as:

> You are charged for each document read, write, and delete that you perform with Cloud Firestore.
> Charges for writes and deletes are straightforward. For writes, each set or update operation counts as a single write.

Meaning that one document created is one write. If the same document is updated later, then Firebase counts it as one more write.

Here is a more detailed table that you can use for [billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations), and an [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example).

It is recommended to view individual product usage in the "Usage" tab for many products in the Firebase console, as this can narrow the product that is causing the elevated usage that you are seeing.

I would highly recommend adding [write and view logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs) to your application; that way, you can monitor how many writes and reads you have.

Comment: What if, when you use .set(), the document already exists? Does that count as a write?